# What is the effect of the "&x=" in a SSRF? Is it something related to encoding?

Tags: web-browser, webserver, web, ssrf

I'm learning SSRF. I learnt that typing `&x=` kinda turn off the rest of an URL (like https://some.website.com/user?id=9&x=.website.com/api/item?id=9)

Everything that comes after the `&x=` part gets ignored. Why is that? Or, if it's not really ignored, then what happens?

Comment: "&" is just to include additional query parameters.  Once the "?" is hit, the rest of the URL will be processed as GET key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not related to encoding in this case.

According to the RFC 3986 Regular Expression of `^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?` does not allow parsing of another `?` after a `&`, which denotes a second and so forth parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The payload ending in `&x=` is being used to stop the remaining path from being appended to the end of the attacker's URL and instead turns it into a parameter (`?x=`) on the query string.